# Vue.js Installation using CLI command, receive some error on my command prompt, Not understand what was that

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

Before I start asking my question first to all tell you everyone that I am new to vue.js, well a few day earlier i decided to learn vue.js, Watching video how to install vue.js using CLI command, follow the instruction as suggested by the tutor in video.

I have receive some error on my command prompt and I am not able to understand what was that, can someone see the error and suggest me where is the problem and how can i resolve this problem.

My system configuration is as follow:

```
Windows system
Operating system - windows 7
64 bit operating system
Node version 10.15.1
NPM version 6.1.0
Vue version 2.9.6
system configuration
```

What error I have receive while submit commands as follow:

```
Deepak@Deepak-PC MINGW64 /e
$ npm install -g vue@2.6.10
+ vue@2.6.10
updated 1 package in 3.292s

Deepak@Deepak-PC MINGW64 /e
$ vue init webpack-simple learn-vue

assert.js:85
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 2173 == 0
at ClientRequest.onConnect 
(C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue- cli\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:160:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:475:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)

Deepak@Deepak-PC MINGW64 /e
$
```

Thanks in advance for give you valuable time to my question

Comment: Use `npm install -g @vue/cli` instead of `npm install -g vue@2.6.10`. Visit https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html for more information about installation of vue-cli.

Answer (score 1):

Use vue-cli instead of vue as:

```
npm install -g vue-cli@2.6.10


vue init webpack-simple learn-vue
```

Comment: No brother, not working showing error :

Deepak@Deepak-PC MINGW64 /e
$ npm install -g vue-cli@2.6.10
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue
C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue-init -> C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue-init
C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue-list -> C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue-list
+ vue-cli@2.6.10
updated 1 package in 5.681s

Answer (score 0):

if npm install -g vue-cli is not working then use

```
npm install -g @vue/cli@2.6.10
```

Answer (score 0):

you could install the vue cli by running `npm i -g @vue/cli` then create a new vue project with vue create newProjectName(new project name is the name of your intended vue project, it could be anything).
Then run `npm run serve`. Hope this helps. Also check the official docs:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create